# Read a three way ouput table in R

Tags: r, output

I hope you can help me.
I would like to know how to read an output in R.

So I have three binary variables Q3A1, Q3A2, Q3A3, each line corresponds to the answer of a subject

| Q3A1 | Q3A2 | Q3A3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |

I wanted to have the number of people for each possible answer, so I wrote the command

```
table(dataQ$Q3A1,dataQ$Q3A2,dataQ$Q3A3)
```

and I got this as an output in R console

```
, ,  = 0


|     | 0  |1 |

| 0   | 90 |16|
| 1   | 80 |61|

   
    , ,  = 1 

|    | 0  |1 |

| 0  | 19 |4 |
| 1  | 52 |13|
```

but I don't know how to read it, which rows and columns corresponds to which variable ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: the first table is for when Q3A3 == 0 and the second for when Q3A3 == 1

Comment: and then in each table which variable is in row and which isin column ?

Comment: table rows are Q3A1, columns are Q3A2, tables are Q3A3